# SQL Server Management Studio 2014 - Show same .sql file in multiple tab groups

Tags: sql-server-2014, ssms

In Notepad++, I can look at the same file in two side-by-side tab groups. In that software, this feature is called "Clone to Over View". Is it possible to do this in SQL Sever Management Studio 2014?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To my knowledge SQL Server Studio doesn't have a clone/compare feature. Having said that, it appears that SoftTree makes a product that integrates into SQL Server Studio allowing you to use Notepad++ as the editor (which looks very cool):

```
http://www.softtreetech.com/sqlassist/more_screenshots.htm

http://www.softtreetech.com/sqlassist/
```

Note: *I have zero affiliation or investment with this company.*

SoftTree looks to be a bit pricy. However, you can get a free plugin to run SQL code from Notepad++ here (I'm liking they way this looks and may have to try it myself):

```
https://github.com/gutkyu/NppDB
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do something similar but different.

1. Open the file you want to view
2. Open a new query tab
3. Right click on the new query tab and select "New Vertical Tab Group"
4. Copy/paste the contents of the original file you opened into the new tab

Instead of looking at the same file in two tabs, you will essentially be creating another file that you can save or not.  Just be careful which file you are making modifications to, if required.

There is a second option, but to my knowledge, it only works horizontally and in the same tab - the split tab feature in SSMS.

[image]

If you click and drag the split tab icon shown above, you can create a split view of the file you are working with.  Again, this only works horizontally, but is another option for you.

[image]